Laravel Websocket cURL error 28 on Event Trigger
I am new to beyondcode/laravel-websockets and followed instructions
.env
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=livequeueing
PUSHER_APP_KEY=livequeueing_key
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=livequeueing_secret
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
PUSHER_HOST="127.0.0.1"
PUSHER_PORT=6001
PUSHER_SCHEME="http"

config/broadcasting
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => false,
                'encrypter' => false,
                'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST'),
                'post' => env('PUSHER_PORT'),
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME'),
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],

I am able to run websockets but when I'm trying to fire an event i get an error:
"exception": "Pusher error: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30005 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://127.0.0.1/apps/livequeueing/events?auth_key=livequeueing_key&auth_timestamp=1729070873&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=29253897d0185617e76994d68351ff89&auth_signature=ca59e85a0c39346f6d592ce4cd824015d57befccbc02460a1958c068ffcda2bd."

What could I have been missing ? Also in my
php.ini
max_execution_time=120
max_input_time=60
memory_limit=512M


Not an actual solution but may come in handy:
I am presently having this particular problem because payload is too large. This error is a "consiquence" of another one for me. You migth want to check that.
Payload size by itself can be configured but of no help, since timeots will still occur.
Also I was having troubles running sockets until i added REVERB_SERVER_ set of variables to env (you can find them in documentation). After that it i was able to launch it successfuly. Had to set same port for reverb server and "app".
And if you are using docker there may also be a problem of ports not being "open", which cand be fixed in docker-compose file.
Hope it helps. My appologies for not being able to give a precise solution.
